# How can I make the title of my BeamerPoster appear on the same page as the actual poster?

Tags: beamer, titles, beamerposter

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0]{beamerposter}
\mode<presentation>{%
  \usetheme{Frankfurt}%
}

\usepackage{mwe}


\title[S. N. A. E. L.]{Social Network Analysis in English Literature}
\author{Sean Allred}
\institute{University College Dublin%
%\\An Col\'aiste Ollscoile, Baile \'Atha Cliath
}
\date{26 April 2013}

\begin{document}\maketitle
\begin{frame}{}
  \begin{block}{Title}
    \lipsum
  \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This produces two posters, one for the title, and another for the actual content.  It must be possible, but every 'desirable' poster (i.e. with the title in the right place) uses an as-yet-indecipherable-to-me `beamertheme*.sty` to do the work.  I've only just started working with Beamer, and everything is still very confusing (although Beamer theme styles seem to be *notoriously* so).

Ideally, I'd just like to have the title centered at the top (in a readable title-size font) and the ability to slap a logo in either corner.

**Logo**:

[image]

Comment: If you need a dummy logo, [this SVG](http://images1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20100922010236/spongebob/images/8/81/Gary_the_Snail.svg) may be appropriate `:)`

Comment: Hi:) Took some freedom to upload a png format of svg using imagemagick command line tool `convert filename.svg filename.png` to make the question and logo as one entity.Hope its ok. your comment may be cleared as well incase you desire.

Comment: Thanks, @texenthusiast.  I always forget that pdfLaTeX and SVG don't play exceptionally nice together - it's something that just *seems right* so I assume it *is right*.  Perfectly fine - that's what the edit button is for. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following answer is based on your code, but please be aware that it is possibile to follow a completely different approach to solve your problem. You may, for example, get rid of the `\title`, `\author`, etc. macros and insert the same information in a normal or custom block enviroment, so to have more control over it. Anyway, the following code tries to follow your MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0]{beamerposter} %2378 x 1682
\mode<presentation>{%
  \usetheme{Frankfurt}%
}

\usepackage{mwe}


\title[S. N. A. E. L.]
{
\parbox{.25\textwidth}{\includegraphics[height=4cm]{dummylogo.png}\hfill}%
\parbox{.5\textwidth}{\hfil \huge Social Network Analysis in English Literature\hfil}%
\parbox{.25\textwidth}{\hfill\includegraphics[height=2cm]{dummylogo.png}}%
}
\author{\Large Sean Allred}
\institute{\Large University College Dublin%
%\\An Col\'aiste Ollscoile, Baile \'Atha Cliath
}
\date{\Large 26 April 2013}



\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{}
\begin{beamercolorbox}{}
\maketitle
\end{beamercolorbox}
\vskip 50mm
  \begin{block}{Title}
    \lipsum
  \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To set the space for the logos in the topleft and right corners three `\parbox` have been created inside `\title`. Depending on the length of the title it may be needed to change the parboxes width (in the example I used .25 for the left and right parboxes and .5 for the center one).

If you want the logo only on one side, just remove one of the two `includegraphics`and leave the parbox empty.

To show the title in the same page of the content I insterted the `\maketitle` inside a `beamercolorbox`.

To change the text size you could use the standard commands (as I did in the example) or scale everything using the option `scale=<value>` when loading the `beamerposter` package

### Removing external margins from the colorbox

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0]{beamerposter} %2378 x 1682

\mode<presentation>{%
  \usetheme{Frankfurt}%
}

\usepackage{mwe}


\title[S. N. A. E. L.]
{
\parbox{.24\textwidth}{\hspace{5pt}\includegraphics[height=4cm]{dummylogo.png}\hfill}%
\parbox{.5\textwidth}{\hfil \huge Social Network Analysis in English Literature\hfil}%
\parbox{.24\textwidth}{\hfill\includegraphics[height=2cm]{dummylogo.png}}%
}
\author{\Large Sean Allred}
\institute{\Large University College Dublin%

}
\date{\Large 26 April 2013}

\setbeamersize{text margin left=0cm,text margin right=0cm} %removes left and right margins 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{}
\vspace{-5pt}             %removes margin between headline and colorbox
\begin{beamercolorbox}{}
\maketitle
\end{beamercolorbox}
\vskip 50mm

\centering\begin{minipage}{82cm}     %introduces a new margin for the content
  \begin{block}{Title}
    \lipsum
  \end{block}
\end{minipage}  
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's a neat way of doing it!!  Much more elegant than what I eventually came up with (which I'll post as another answer for completeness).  I suppose the absolute key element I was missing was to put `\maketitle` somehow inside the `frame` environment.  (although wrapping it with `beamercolorbox` looks much nice than the default in my opinion!)

Comment: Although as an addendum - is there any way to have the `beamercolorbox` flush both left and right (i.e. a blue strip along the top)?

Comment: Not the cleanest solution, but you can use `\setbeamersize{text margin left=0cm,text margin right=0cm}` in the preamble so that the colorbox extends over the white left and right margins, and then include the rest of the frame in a centered minipage (so to reintroduce margins for other blocks). If you wish I can add an example to my answer.

Comment: If you'd like, but the tools are enough for me.  Thanks again!

Comment: I updated it because in the comment I forgot to say that to remove the white margin between the colorbox and the headline from the Frankfurt theme you can add negative  `vspace` before the colorbox, and also that after removing the margins you need to reduce the width of the left and right parboxes, so that the logos will stay inside the frame.

Answer (score 5):

My humble and un-LaTeX-y attempt, using a combination of `textpos` and a redefinition of `\maketitle` (and an interesting use thereof, note that it is typeset as the title of a frame).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{textpos}

\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0]{beamerposter}
\mode<presentation>{%
  \usetheme{Frankfurt}%
}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
  \begin{textblock}{.1}(10,3)
    \includegraphics[width=4em]{logo}
  \end{textblock}
  \vspace*{1ex}%
  \begin{center}%
    \Huge\inserttitle\\%
    \LARGE\insertauthor\\%
    \Large\insertinstitute%
  \end{center}%
  \vspace*{-1ex}%
}

\setbeamerfont{block title}{size=\LARGE}

\title[S. N. A. E. L.]{Social Network Analysis in English Literature}
\author{Sean Allred}
\institute{University College Dublin, Department of Computer Science and Informatics%
%\\An Col\'aiste Ollscoile, Baile \'Atha Cliath
}
\date{26 April 2013}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{\maketitle}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
      \begin{block}{Background}
        Why, hello there!  \LaTeX{} is a tool for professional
        typesetting.  It is used by academics, researchers, and
        professionals \emph{all over the world}.  It is written in
        plain text in the \LaTeX{} format.  Like HTML, \LaTeX{} is a
        \textsl{markup language}; while Turing complete for all my
        geeks out there, it is designed to be simple to understand
        even in its plain-text form.
      \end{block}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
      \begin{block}{Methods}
        Writing \LaTeX{} is easy: all you need is an editor (any text
        editor will do) and what we call a \TeX{} distribution.  A
        \TeX{} distribution is just a fancy way of saying `everything
        you need to produce a document with \LaTeX{}.  This usually
        includes the main programs (\texttt{tex}, \texttt{latex},
        \texttt{pdftex}, \texttt{pdflatex}, etc.) and a slew of other
        helpful, supplementary programs (\texttt{texdoc},
        \texttt{texhash}, etc.).  This may seem like a lot, but the
        only program you will ever have any dealings with on a regular
        basis is in fact \texttt{pdflatex},\footnote{\texttt{tex} and
          \texttt{latex} turn these source files into what is called a
          DVI, an even more portable format.} the program that will
        take a properly-formatted \LaTeX{} source file and turn it
        into a PDF.
      \end{block}
      \begin{block}{Conclusions}
        I am \emph{not} qualified to draw conclusions.  Ha!
      \end{block}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image: output]

Comment: This seems very elegant to me, what's "un-LaTeX-y" about it?