# How can I publish a document that uses resources I don't personally have access to?

Tags: publishing, copyright

The high-resolution/vector images of many institution logos are held under copyright and strict restrictions.  I don't have access to these logos personally, and I've been unsuccessful in asking for them in person for the purposes of building the document.

I have pondered, though, perhaps giving my supervisor (who can pass it on to someone who has the authority, if necessary) some sort of *complete package* to build the document - just add images.  I was considering a makefile for some time, but that seems too technical.

I also *just* remembered DVI does this sort of 'referencing', so perhaps I can use that.

What would be the best way to make such a 'complete package' so that the end-builder doesn't need *any* knowledge of TeX or anything?

---

*UPDATE:* I now do have the resource that was previously unavailable, but the concept of 'a complete package' ready for publishing is still really interesting, if anyone has done something similar before.

If you have, you can assume the publisher...

- has all resources needed to 'finalize' the document
- does *not* have a TeX distribution
- is computer-literate, but not to the extent of complex command-line wizardry (but running a script is within reason).

Comment: I guess if you knew the filenames of the restricted resources you could use placeholder images like `example-image.pdf` and script a search-and-replace.  But the end user would still need to run TeX.  And more broadly, if someone can run a `makefile` they can probably edit a `.tex` file so this might not solve any actual problems.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang The 'running TeX' bit is the part I need to avoid; I can't possibly plain *expect* them to have a TeX distribution.  The `makefile` approach *could* work, but it would *also* require running TeX.  (A simple double-click can execute a makefile.)

Comment: There _may_ be pdf editors with a command line interface that are sophisticated enough to replace dummy images with real ones. pdftk (http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) doesn't promise that much, though, unless your images are whole pages (unlikely).

Comment: @SeanAllred presuming you are affiliated to a university,  it's possible to borrow university logo from thesis templates/website to present in your conference posters and fliers. convince admin the genuineness of how you use the logo and it's promotion benefits etc..

Comment: @texenthusiast That's a good idea, but as I was looking around I noted that I only had access to pretty low-resolution logos which would look *horrific* scaled to 5cm, [as in an a0 poster](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109389).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The traditional publishing term for this is `FPO` (for position only) --- place a rough proxy in lieu of the image you want, put `FPO` on top if it, then provide the .pdf to the printer --- it's then the responsibility of someone further down the line to replace it w/ the real image. Any decent printer should have a copy of the Acrobat plug-in PitStop by Enfocus or some similar tool to accomplish this.

I suppose if the print shop had someone who knew (La)TeX, one could work up some sort of draft mode option which the print shop could then turn off which would then look for and link in the real versions, but that's something the print shop will have to set up, not something a user can enable w/o using an intermediate format like .dvi which allows for such re-direction.