# Funny stuff in a Beamer title irreparably messes with the PDF metadata

Tags: beamer, titles, metadata

I have the following `beamer` presentation:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{%
\parbox{.25\textwidth}{funny}%
\parbox{.5\textwidth}{Real Title}%
\parbox{.25\textwidth}{stuff}}

\hypersetup{pdftitle={Real Title}}

\begin{document}
Hello, World!
\end{document}
```

and no matter what I try (removing `hyperref` and using `\pdfinfo`, for example), the title always comes out as the entire ASCII portion of the `\title`, less control sequences:

> .25funny.5Real Title.25stuff

Is there no way to *absolutely* set the title of the PDF using only LaTeX?  (I know metadata editors exist, but this could be considered a bug in some lines of thought.)

---

I should note that the problem is not reproducible in `article`.

Comment: The problem here is `hyperref`, it can only handle text. If you create a titlepage in your document, the title looks fine. If you try using your title as a section title in `article`, the navigation will be messed up as well. I'm not aware of any way to trick `hyperref` into doing non-text right...

Comment: IMO formatting macros like `\parbox` should not go into a moving argument such as for `\title`.  If you want to change how the title is shown patch `\maketitle`.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I completely agree, but I don't really know how to 'patch' `\maketitle` in the same sense I'd 'patch' some listing; there is probably a lot going on in `beamer`'s maketitle, very little of which I would understand at a glance.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang that is a really sensible advice. Do you mind if I add it to my answer? (That is, of course, if you're not planning to give an answer.)

Comment: If anyone knows a better way of doing it off the top of their head, [more answers are welcome](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109389).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Sean's right, digging into beamer internals is intimidating, so it's not trivial. I'm toying with an answer now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `\texorpdfstring`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{%
\texorpdfstring{\parbox{.25\textwidth}{funny}%
\parbox{.5\textwidth}{Real Title}%
\parbox{.25\textwidth}{stuff}}{Real Title}}

\begin{document}
Hello, World!
\end{document}
```

Since some themes use the title in other places (in the footline, for example), it would alos be a good idea to use the optional argument, so this will be picked up for displaying the title in footlines:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title[Title]{%
\texorpdfstring{\parbox{.25\textwidth}{funny}%
\parbox{.5\textwidth}{Real Title}%
\parbox{.25\textwidth}{stuff}}{Real Title}}

\begin{document}
Hello, World!
\end{document}
```

By the way, there's no need to load `hyperref` with `beamer`.

As **Matthew Leingang** mentioned in a comment, a more sensible approach would be  to make a modification to the way the title is built. In the following example I modified the `title page` template to insert information using three `\parboxes` in the title field. The `\triplebox` command receives three mandatory arguments: the first and third ones will be used for the lateral `\parbox`es, and the second one will be used for the title; there's also an optional argument that can be used to pass an optional argument to `\title`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\def\insertfirst{}
\def\insertsecond{}

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{mydefault}[1][]
{
  \vbox{}
  \vfill
  \begin{centering}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0pt,center,#1]{title}
      \usebeamerfont{title}%
      \parbox{.25\linewidth}{\centering\insertfirst}%
      \parbox{0.5\linewidth}{\centering\inserttitle}%
      \parbox{.25\linewidth}{\centering\insertsecond}\par%
      \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
        \vskip0.25em%
        {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
      \fi%     
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{author}
      \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{institute}
      \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{date}
      \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
    \end{beamercolorbox}\vskip0.5em
    {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\par}
  \end{centering}
  \vfill
}
\makeatother

\newcommand\triplebox[4][]{%
  \gdef\insertfirst{#2}\gdef\insertsecond{#4}\title[]{#3}
}

\triplebox{funny}{Real Title}{stuff}
\author{Author}
\institute{Institute}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the macro and the tip!  (It didn't hit me that `beamer` already does its own hyperlinking.)

Comment: @SeanAllred please see my updated answer.

Comment: Good answer.  If you look at mine you'll see I took a slightly different route with `\addtobeamertemplate`.

Comment: @SeanAllred No. You only use the optional argument if you want to provide an optional argument for `\title`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I'm answering the broader question “How can I alter the display of the title in beamer?”.  In my comment I said that I think “the right way” to do this is to alter the formatting macros (i.e., `\maketitle`) instead of the metadata-declaration macros (i.e., `\title`).

Here is an example.  Explanation follows.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usetheme{AnnArbor}

\title{Real Title}

\makeatletter
\addtobeamertemplate{title page}{%
    \let\beamerorig@inserttitle\inserttitle%
    \renewcommand{\inserttitle}{%
       \makebox[0.20\textwidth][c]{funny}
       \makebox[0.5 \textwidth][c]{\beamerorig@inserttitle}
       \makebox[0.20\textwidth][c]{stuff}
    }
}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
Hello, World!
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample code output]

I used the fancy `AnnArbor` theme so you can see that the display of “Real Title” in the footer isn't affected.

The titling macros (which I found with `grep`) are found in `beamerbasetitle.sty`:

```
\def\maketitle{\ifbeamer@inframe\titlepage\else\frame{\titlepage}\fi}
%...
\def\titlepage{\usebeamertemplate*{title page}\@thanks}
```

We see that for flexibility `\maketitle` uses beamer's templating system.  The `title page` template is usually defined in an *inner* theme.  Here is the one from `beamerinnerthemedefault.sty` (again, found with `grep`):

```
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{default}[1][]
{
  \vbox{}
  \vfill
  \begin{centering}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{title}
      \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
      \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
        \vskip0.25em%
        {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
      \fi%     
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{author}
      \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{institute}
      \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{date}
      \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
    \end{beamercolorbox}\vskip0.5em
    {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\par}
  \end{centering}
  \vfill
}
```

The part that is inside the `{beamercolorbox}[...]{title}` environment is where the title goes.  At this point you have to decide if you want to create a new `title page` template with `\defbeamertemplate`, similar to that template but with alterations inside the title beamercolorbox, and invoke it with `\usebeamertemplate`, or hack the way that `\inserttitle` displays the title.  I chose the latter, because (a) you don't have to know which template is used, and (b) beamer provides commands to locally alter templates.

So my code uses `\addtobeamertemplate` to preprend to the current `title page` template (whichever is in use) a patch to the `\inserttitle` command.  However you want the title really displayed should go there.