# How to get two logos side by side

Tags: floats, double-sided

I need to put a logo left side aligned and a logo on the right side, I also need to add text between both logos?

[image: Two logos side by side]

I've reviewed the questions about figures side by side, subfigure and minipage, but I can't get it

How should I do it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Right now I have no idea what you are asking. Which 'next one' are you referring to? Do the tags for this question have anything to do with it?

Comment: In fact I didn't know what tags to use. The next one is the image. I'll read the guide, surely. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can use the method I did at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/109607 using `\includegraphics` instead of the funny stuff.

Comment: Thanks, it's going to work, but how can I align the first image to left?

Comment: If you know the widths, put each into their own \parbox[c]{}{}, assuming you want to align their centers.

Comment: Hello imarban I designed time ago a page as you need but for a UNAM thesis, in my case the challenge was to create a titlepage with two images aligned vertically. I used minipage and graphicx without subfigure environment for that. Let me find the code and I'll explain you how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
  \begin{center}
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
  \begin{tabular}{>{\raggedleft}m{2.5cm}>{\centering}m{\dimexpr\textwidth - 5cm\relax}>{\raggedright}m{2.5cm}}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}%
  &%
  \textbf{\large INSTITUTO POLITECNICO NACIONAL} \\[5pt]%
  \textbf{\large ESCUELA SUPERIOR DE COMPUTO}%
  &%
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image} %
  \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `minipage`s:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}   %% just for demo
\begin{document}
  \noindent
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.2\textwidth}    %% b or t, default is c
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}[b][2cm]{0.6\textwidth}
    \centering\bfseries\large
    Some text comes here \vfill
    Some thing here \vfill
    Some text
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.2\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
  \end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]