# Beamerposter heading

Tags: beamerposter

I have awfully lot of troubles trying to make just a simple centered heading using `beamerposter` package. I am totally lost. Could you please provide any minimal working example?

Of course, I've been at simple examples like in [here](https://github.com/deselaers/latex-beamerposter) and have read questions like [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109389/how-can-i-make-the-title-of-my-beamerposter-appear-on-the-same-page-as-the-actua) but I still don't get it. It seem to me that without an undecypherable `*.sty` it just doesn't work. Am I missing a simple solution?

*Note:* I've tried the answer from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109389/how-can-i-make-the-title-of-my-beamerposter-appear-on-the-same-page-as-the-actua) but it didn't work for me. Maybe if there could be something without `mwe`?

Comment: What does " it didn't work for me." means exactly. Do you have `beamerposter.sty` installed in your machine?

Comment: Yes, I do. It was a problem with includegraphics. I've fixed that already. But is this cheat the only way to make the simple heading?

Comment: No. I'll add a simple example below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example; the [`textpos`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/textpos) package was used to place the blocks at desired locations:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usepackage[orientation=landscape,size=a0,scale=1.4,debug]{beamerposter}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1cm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1cm}


\title[A simple poster]{An example of the \texttt{beamerposter} package}
\author{The Author}
\institute{Thye Institute}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\begin{textblock}{110}(5,3)
\centering
\maketitle
\end{textblock}

\begin{textblock}{110}(5,20)
\begin{block}{A test block}
Some test text.
\end{block}
\end{textblock}

\begin{textblock}{110}(5,25)
\begin{columns}
\column{.32\textwidth}
\begin{block}{A test block}
Some test text.
\end{block}
\column{.32\textwidth}
\begin{alertblock}{A test alert block}
Some test text.
\end{alertblock}
\column{.32\textwidth}
\begin{exampleblock}{A test example block}
Some test text.
\end{exampleblock}
\end{columns}
\end{textblock}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

There are other alternatives for your posters such as [`tikzposter`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzposter).